# ERROR => ERROR => SMTP-AUTH: Authentication to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed

Tags: shell

I am trying to send an email using below command but i am getting below error:

```
Command executed:
/usr/bin/sendemail -v -f "mymail@gmail.com" -u "Re : Alerts Script" \
   -t "$EMAILS" -s "smtp.gmail.com:587" -o tls=yes -xu "my@gmail.com" \
   -xp "Password" -m "$Msg"
```

I tried with port 25, Still same error getting.
If i use 465 port getting below error

> ERROR => smtp.gmail.com:465 returned a zero byte response to our query.

```
/usr/bin/sendemail -v -f "mymail@gmail.com" -u "Re : Alerts Script" \
  -t "$EMAILS" -s "smtp.gmail.com:587" -o tls=yes -xu "my@gmail.com" \
  -xp "Password" -m "$Msg"
```

Email should go for given email id's

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue and could resolve it. You can use the tls auto, 587 port command. Able to successfully send an email using Gmail SMTP.

```
/usr/bin/sendemail -f "mymail@gmail.com" -u "Re : Alerts Script" -t "$EMAILS" -s "smtp.gmail.com:587" -o tls=auto -xu "mymail@gmail.com" -xp "Password" -m "$Msg"
```

Also, you have to apply couple of settings in Gmail.

1. Enable IMAP
2. Allow less secure app
3. Review suspicious activity and mark 'That's me' to allow communication.

Comment: I had all that enabled and it still wasn't working. However, for some reason when I logged in to Gmail from a browser on that same server (Windows) it started working.

Comment: I second that comment. sendEmail worked for me as soon as I have made a successful login with a browser from the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error for me in Windows (should work in any OS), I had to go into my Gmail account/Security/App Passwords on the web and generate a 16-digit password for App:"Mail" and Device:"Windows Computer" (you can create a custom device too) to give special access to the device where I was running SendEmail.

Per Google: "App passwords let you sign in to your Google Account from apps on devices that don't support 2-Step Verification."

Then I used that 16-digit password in SendEmail instead of my gmail password and it finally went through.

```
c:\sendemail\sendemail -o tls=yes -t recipient@email.*** -m Title HELLO -f [myaccount]@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu [myaccount]@gmail.com -xp **************** -l C:\sendemail\logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in windows you need to add sendEmail to your firewall.

Comment: and how can you do that? Good approach, but please write a detailed and clear answer.

Comment: I did not have to add SendEmail to my firewall on my Windows device to resolve this issue. See my answer below for what worked for me.